# blank pdf report in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, reporting-services

Everything works fine on my local machine and in our test site. Also both test and production sites have certificates installed. There is also an embedded image in the pdf report. I am not sure why it doesn't work in production as against the test site. In production it downloads a blank pdf file.

This is the code:

```
            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("objDataSet", models);

            localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
            string reportType = "PDF";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;

            //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
            //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx
            string deviceInfo =
            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.75in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0.75in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            //Render the report
            renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=abc." + fileNameExtension);
            Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes); // create the file
            Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
            return null;
```

From Fiddler Raw headers:

PRO:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: application/pdf
content-disposition: attachment; filename=abc.pdf
Date: Wed, 23 May 2012 14:19:59 GMT
Content-Length: 23975
ETag: "pv11fd8c346df09ccc63c9a6c72b8b776d"
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
X-PvInfo: [S10201.C11680.A12679.RA12754.G0.U59AB06B0].[OT/pdf.OG/documents]

UAT:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/pdf
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
content-disposition: attachment; filename=abc.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 May 2012 14:59:46 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 23681

The mime type is set to .pdf : application/pdf

Also an interesting thing I noticed was the file size of the pdf (23 KB)  is pretty much the same as I would get from my test website only difference being one pdf is completely blank the other filled with data.

Comment: have you tried to execute the same report at production using report manager and exported the output to PDF?

Comment: I do not have report manager installed on the test site or the production site. The report is being generated through C# code and it works fine to export with OutputFormat set to Image.